# How to hide square brackets in my UI output using dictionary in Combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to hide the square brackets in my UI output.

[image]

I think it's a pretty easy workaround, but I can't figure it out.

My code for adding items into Combobox:

```
conn_mode.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"1", "WiFi"},
    {"2", "GSM"},
    {"3", "Offline"},
}.ToList();
conn_mode.ValueMember = "Key";
conn_mode.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

And I'm using this code to align items in combobox into center:

```
private void cur_mul_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{       
    ComboBox cbx = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cbx != null)
    {
    // Always draw the background
    e.DrawBackground();

    // Drawing one of the items?
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        // Set the string alignment.  Choices are Center, Near and Far
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        // Set the Brush to ComboBox ForeColor to maintain any ComboBox color settings
        // Assumes Brush is solid
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(cbx.ForeColor);

        // If drawing highlighted selection, change brush
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;

        // Draw the string
        e.Graphics.DrawString(cbx.Items[e.Index].ToString(), cbx.Font, brush, e.Bounds, sf);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this code - as is - does not output the items shown in the image. You are doing something else. i.e. owner draw...  Please clarify.

Comment: I have set DrawMode on "OwnerDrawFixed" yes. Is that it?

Comment: `var itemText = conn_mode.GetItemText(conn_mode.Items[e.Index]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always call the [`GetItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?view=netframework-4.8) method to get item's text regardless how the `ComboBox` is populated.

```cs
var cbx = sender as ComboBox;
var itemText = cbx.GetItemText(cbx.Items[e.Index]);

e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, ...);
```

If you need to display a formatted string like `ValueMember` + `DisplayMember`, your data source here is `Dictionary<string, string>`, then the items are a collection of type `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. Therefore:

```cs
var cbx = sender as ComboBox;
var item = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)cbx.Items[e.Index];
var itemText = $"{item.Key}, {item.Value}";

e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, ...);
```

Otherwise, you'll get what the `.ToString()` method override returns for the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` type when you pass `cbx.Items[e.Index].ToString()`.

**Side Notes**

- You must dispose of `sf` and `brush` instances or create them by using the `using` statement.

```cs
var cbx = sender as ComboBox;
var item = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)cbx.Items[e.Index];
var itemText = $"{item.Key}, {item.Value}";
var foreColor = cbx.ForeColor;

if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;

using (var brush = new SolidBrush(foreColor))
using (var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic))
{
    sf.Alignment = sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, cbx.Font, brush, e.Bounds, sf);
}
```

- Use the [`TextRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead to draw the text on controls.

```cs
var cbx = sender as ComboBox;
var item = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)cbx.Items[e.Index];
var itemText = $"{item.Key}, {item.Value}";
var foreColor = cbx.ForeColor;

if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;

TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, itemText, cbx.Font, e.Bounds, foreColor, 
    TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
```

Comment: I've tried it out, but i get an error saying: **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:** 'InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'. Arg_ParamName_Name ArgumentOutOfRange_ActualValue'

Comment: ok i got it...i needed to change the conn_mode with cbx. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Below Code Adding Dictionary values in Combo Box

```
conn_mode.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"1", "WiFi"},
    {"2", "GSM"},
    {"3", "Offline"},
}.ToList();
conn_mode.ValueMember = "Key";
conn_mode.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuiI0.jpg)

Use the below code to remove Square brackets while adding into the Combo Box.

```
Conn_Mode.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        {"1", "WiFi"},
                        {"2", "GSM"},
                        {"3", "Offline"},
                    }.Select(d => d.Key + "," + d.Value).ToList();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3hah.png)